# Publish applet with maker webhook

Tags: raspberry-pi, applet, iot, webhooks, ifttt

I want to publish my applet with a maker webhook to my raspberry pi. For some reason it doesn't allow me to publish the app when I use a maker webhook in it.I'm not sure why it doesn't allow me or if it's even possible at all.

There isn't any error in the applet either as it works perfectly fine in private mode. I also have seen some applets by other users that use the maker webhooks in their applet. So I think it must be possible.

If somebody could answer this question who has published an applet before with webhooks or what I could be doing wrong. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you publishing through the Maker Platform? https://platform.ifttt.com/maker/guide

Comment: @Eric Cochran Yes, I'm trying to publish it from the Maker platform. I can publish any other combo of services, but from the moment I use maker webhooks the publish button is grayed-out. I don't think there is anything wrong with the applet settings and I didn't add any filter code. It only says "This Applet is private and uses one or more services that prevent it from being published"

Comment: @eric-cochran or do you really need a service to publish your own webhook ?

Comment: Right now, that's the product decision. Applets made with Maker can’t be published if they use the Maker Webhooks (previously Maker) service. Tweet @IFTTT about it. :P

Comment: @eric-cochran Thanks for your help Eric. It was for a school project. We connected a robot capable of showing emotions to IFTTT services. Every time a service got triggered, the robot showed an emotion and said a message accordingly to the service. We managed to do without a partner account as a proof of concept for the partner account was a tad bit too expensive for us for now.

Comment: Wow, that's super cool!